# Why are the leaves on my Japanese cherry tree turning yellow?

Tags: trees, tree-care

I have a Japanese cherry tree in my front yard. (I live in a hot, high-altitude desert climate.) This is my first spring in this house, and last year the tree had significant die-off. I'm guessing it's due to the previous owners not watering their yard at all last year until I moved in in June.

The tree had beautiful blossoms, and the leaves seem to be growing in well. Lots of new branches growing too. However, some of the leaves are starting to turn yellow. It's only a small fraction of all the leaves, and it's in a couple of places on the tree. What's going on?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. The tree looks like it's going dormant, but if it's your growing season, I would suspect it just needs fertilizer (probably nitrogen). That's usually the cause of chlorosis (yellowing). However, other possibilities are things like overwatering, fungal disease, pH problems, and other things.